# MVC Model Binding Not Working via AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

Having a little trouble with MVC model binding via AJAX.

Can someone tell me why the CreateTransfereeDetails property is not binding, it always comes back as 'null'.

Model:

```
public class ResolveProfileSelectionRequiredModel
{
    public CreateTransfereeModel CreateTransfereeDetails { get; set; }

    public bool NewTransfereeSelected { get; set; }
}

public class CreateTransfereeModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Transferee Name:")]
    public string TransfereeName { get; set; }
}
```

Html:

```
<input type="text" id="TransfereeName" />
<input type="hidden" id="NewTrasnfereeSelected" />
```

JavaScript:

```
var createTransfereeDetails =
{
    "TransfereeName": $("#TransfereeName").val()
};

$.ajax({
    url: "/myurl",
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        CreateTransfereeDetails: createTransfereeDetails,
        NewTransfereeSelected: $("#NewTransfereeSelected").val()
    },
    success: function (result) {
        //
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //
    },
    complete: function () {
        //
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `name attribute` on input fields inside form. `Name attribute's values`are automatically assigned to model's properties.

```
<form method="post" id="frm">
<input type="text" name="id="TransfereeName" " id="TransfereeName" />
<input type="hidden" name="NewTrasnfereeSelected"  id="NewTrasnfereeSelected" />
<input type="button" onclick="submit()" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and use serialize() function of jquery to pass data using ajax

```
function submit(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/myurl",
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#frm').serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            //
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //
        },
        complete: function () {
            //
        }
    });
}
```