# AllowHtml not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm building a Content Management System to allow people other than me to update stuff on the site.

I have a front-facing HTML form that sends data, via AJAX, to a controller:

```
// CONTROLLER
[ValidateInput(false)]
public void CarAJAX()
{
    CarAdmin CA = new CarAdmin();
    CA.UpdateCar(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request);
}
```

This data will have HTML, so I keep getting an error in my Model:

```
// MODEL
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Site.Models
{
    public class CarAdmin
    {
        public String id { get; set; }
        [AllowHtml]
        public String HTML_Stuff { get; set; }

        public CarAdmin(){}

        public void UpdateCar(HttpRequest Request)
        {
            HTML_Stuff = Request.Form["HTML_Stuff"]; // <-- ERROR HAPPENS HERE!!!!!!

            // sanitation and validation

            String Select = String.Format("UPDATE Car Set HTML_Stuff = {0} WHERE id = {1}", HTML_Stuff, id);

            // Execute DB Command
        }
    }
}
```

As shown in the code, I'm getting an error when I try to set a member equal to a request variable that has HTML.

Edit: The error is 'A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected'

Here's what I've tried:

- [Change the validation mode in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672855/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client-mvc4), but I don't want to change the validation for my entire site, when only one variable will have HTML.
- `[AllowHtml]` in the Model, however I'm still getting the same error - as if `[AllowHtml]` did nothing at all.
- `[ValidateInput(false)]` in the Controller, similar to `AllowHtml`, it seems to have no affect whatsoever.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: "not working", "I'm getting an error ": please be more specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow user to input HTML in asp.net MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621272/allow-user-to-input-html-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @ken2k I added the error: a potentially dangerous Request.Form value detected.

Comment: You must create model object within a controller and set info from request there so remove the Request method parameter from UpdateCar(). There you then sanitize input based on the set property and push it to the database.

Comment: @fsacer I set the variables up in the Controller, rather than the model, as you specified, but I still got the same error.

Comment: @TravisHeeter try out my answer just to be sure that is not working.

Comment: @fsacer I tried your answer, but I still got an `HttpRequestValidationException`

Comment: @TravisHeeter check the updates in the answer :) I hope it helps.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem. **"requestValidationMode="2.0""** was set in web.config, **[AllowHtml]** was also set on proper property and I still got the error "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value detected...".

But I observed that the controller method actually was called (I was able to debug the method) so this had to meant that validation is in fact turned off. In Call Stack I noticed repeatedly occurring of classes around cache like **"System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule"** and this led me to an idea that this has **something to do with cache** I had turned off on the whole controller like this "**[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]"**.

Based on this I tried to also set Location of the cache to OutputCacheLocation.None and this did the trick. So I ended up with **[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]** **working and finally not validating and not failing my requests**.

Comment: Adding the OutputCache attribute to the controller also worked for me, rather bizarrely

Comment: Not sure why that should work, but it did the trick for me - thanks!

Comment: Great Scott! How bizarre. Plus 1 beer from me. (Let's start a new stackexchange fork called BeerExchange. Credit beers for solutions. Could be a huge winner.)

Comment: This worked without  "requestValidationMode="2.0"" ...well done figuring THAT on out :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
// CONTROLLER
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CarAJAX(CarAdmin model)
{
    model.UpdateCar();
}

// MODEL
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Site.Models
{
    public class CarAdmin
    {
        private string html;

        public String id { get; set; }
        [AllowHtml]
        public String HTML_Stuff { 
            get
            { 
                return html; 
            }
            set
            { 
                // sanitation and validation on "value"
                html = value;
            }
        }

        public CarAdmin(){}

        public void UpdateCar()
        {
            String Select = String.Format("UPDATE Car Set HTML_Stuff = {0} WHERE id = {1}", HTML_Stuff, id);

            // Execute DB Command
        }
    }
}
```

I also noticed that you are validating inside a method. It would probably be better, if you do that when setting the property.

**EDIT:**
I researched quite a bit on the topic. You actually need to bind model to the controller using AJAX. Please look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121458/mvc-model-binding-not-working-via-ajax-request). I'm not sure of extents of your code, but I think you also need `ActionResult` to return within controller. [There](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.118).aspx) are nice examples of what to return from `ActionResult`.

Answer (score 0):

just put [ValidateInput(false)] on controller

Answer (score -1):

You should do it as-

Create a separate class with entities those are required-

```
public class EntityDto {
        public String id { get; set; }
        [AllowHtml]
        public String HTML_Stuff { get; set; }
}
```

And then use it in your controller method-

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public void UpdateCar(EntityDto model)
{
    var html_stuff = model.HTML_Stuff; 

    // sanitation and validation

    String Select = String.Format("UPDATE Car Set HTML_Stuff = {0} WHERE id = {1}", html_stuff , id);

    // Execute DB Command
}
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: How do I send a model to a controller via AJAX?

Comment: Where would that method then sit. I think passing model to that method is unnecessary.

Comment: @TravisHeeter,  You don't need! It needs the name of the form elements must match with this model.