# ASP.NET MVC: Output validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc

I am using the following method inside my ASP.NET MVC project to get some XML-data from another web service:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    try
    {
        byte[] reqContent = Helper.GetBytes(Request.Unvalidated.Form["xml"]);

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("url");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "text/xml";
        request.ContentLength = reqContent.Length;
        request.GetRequestStream().Write(reqContent, 0, reqContent.Length);

        string responseXml = null;

        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                responseXml = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        return Content(responseXml, "text/xml");
    }

    catch(Exception)
    {
        return Json(new { Error = true });
    }
}
```

The request inside the action works perfect and I get the right response when I debug the code. But unfortunately when I look at the Chrome Debug tools, the response code from my Action (not the request sent using `WebRequest`) is 500 with the error: "**A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (xml=somexml).**".

Is there some sort of output validation or do I miss something else here? Also the body of the POST-Request to the `MyAction` controller method consists of XML data, but using the `ValidateInput(false)`-attribute and the `Unvalidated`-property of the `Request` object, I get no exception and all works fine inside the method.

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

Thanks to the answer which I marked as accepted, I do not only changed the input validation on up to date standards, I also dug deeper into possible causes and realized that the problem was the global `OutputCacheAttribute`. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115194/allowhtml-not-working) finally solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC is still validating the POST request before you hit your Action. The new way to go is to attribute the property that shall hold the XML with `[AllowHtml]`. `[ValidateInput(false)]` is deprecated. 
See [Securing Your ASP.NET Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en_en/magazine/hh708755.aspx).

```
public class PostXmlModel {
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Xml {get; set;}
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(PostXmlModel postData) {
    string xml = postData.Xml;
    // ...
}
```

PS: to make `[ValidateInput(false)]` work, you would also need to set `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` in the web.config (not recommended). See [Allow user to input html in asp net mvc validateinput or allowhtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621272/allow-user-to-input-html-in-asp-net-mvc-validateinput-or-allowhtml).